# Remove Double Quotes from a String Read from CSV File in Java

Tags: java, string, split, double, quotes

I'm trying to read following data:

Object State, Host Name Port
"Disconnected","XYZ.ABC.COM","10101"
"Disconnected","XYZ.ABC.COM","10101"

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(outputFileName);
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            line = line.replace("\"", "");
            String[] tokens = line.split(",");
            System.out.println(tokens[0]);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        try {
            bufferedReader.close();
            fileWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
}
```

There are following cases:
1.
double quotes, if replace by nothing ("") then output file that I write after altering the code has some unreadable characters.
2. If I replace double quotes with space or nothing ("") split function doesn't work after second line for rest of tokens except first column of first line and first column for rest of the lines. For second line's second token[1] I get ArrayIndexOutofBound Error.

Please Help. I'm Stuck Here!!

Comment: https://tburette.github.io/blog/2014/05/25/so-you-want-to-write-your-own-CSV-code/

Comment: Do you need to write the method by yourself ?there are other open source tools available for doing the same.